# Lookup the 1st or nth appearance of value between two dates

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet, vlookup

[image: example]

In the example, column C is used to track the fast food consumed.  The goal is to set up cell H2 to find the 1st fast food consumed between the dates in cell F1 and F2.  H3 will be used to find the 2nd fast food consumed between the dates.  The closest formula I found for H2 is:

{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$17,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$17=$C$1,ROW($C$2:$C$17)-1,""),COLUMNS($H$1:H1))),"")}

However, that one brings up the 1st fast food appearance of the entire spreadsheet (Pizza) and does not provide a way to restrict the dates.

Is there a way to get the name of the 1st or nth fast food consumed between specified dates?

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I have WPS Office version 11.2.0.11074

Comment: WPS is not Excel.

Comment: I take it you're not here to help

Comment: In Excel you can use the `FILTER` function to limit the range you are searching.

Comment: Was looking for something that would filter within the formula.  Another one that is closer to what is trying to be done here is: 

{=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$17,SMALL(IF($C$2:$C$17=$C$1,ROW($C$2:$C$17)-ROW($C$2)+1),ROWS($C$1:$C2))),"")}

Copying that formula down column H will list each fast food in order of its first appearance on the entire spreadsheet.  Trying to add something to the formula that filters the list to each fast food as it first appears between the dates listed in F2 and F3.  Any ideas?

Comment: WPS Office solution - select the cell where you want to show the 1st item that shows up between dates (H2 in my example). Click the Name box (upper left corner above column A), type in the range of the column where you want your list (H2:H17 in my example). Hit enter. In the formula box, type in a filter formula with the proper parameters.  In my example it would be: =FILTER(A2:A17,(C2:C17=C1)*(B2:B701>=F1)*(B2:B701<=F2)). Hit ctrl+shift+enter.  That will list the items in order of appearance between dates down the column you choose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WPS Office solution - select the cell where you want to show the 1st item that shows up between dates (H2 in my example). Click the Name box (upper left corner above column A), type in the range of the column where you want your list (H2:H17 in my example). Hit enter. In the formula box, type in a filter formula with the proper parameters. In my example it would be: `=FILTER(A2:A17,(C2:C17=C1)*(B2:B701>=F1)*(B2:B701<=F2))`. Hit ctrl+shift+enter. That will list the items in order of appearance between dates down the column you choose.